# Sockets Blocking :( How do i get out?

Tags: c, windows, linux, sockets

Here is server code i took from [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms884939.aspx). Below it is my main which needs to run `void important_code(bool);`. I have always had this problem when using pipes and sockets on both linux and windows.

How do i exit the [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) when i want to quit my app? Assume important_code is always executed on the same thread after the socket code. How would i do that?

I know this is windows code but i get this problem under linux as well

bonus test code: If you comment out main2() in my main function and uncomment the loop you can exit cleanly with ctrl+c. With socket code the blocking `select` prevents me from doing so. How do i solve this?

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define DEFAULT_FAMILY  AF_UNSPEC
#define DEFAULT_SOCKTYPE SOCK_STREAM
#define DEFAULT_PORT  "1234"
#define BUFFER_SIZE   23    // length of "WinCE Echo Test Packet"

void Print(TCHAR *pFormat, ...)
{
    va_list ArgList;
    TCHAR Buffer[256];
    va_start (ArgList, pFormat);
    (void)StringCchPrintf(Buffer, 256, pFormat, ArgList);

#ifndef UNDER_CE
    _putts(Buffer);
#else
    printf("%s",Buffer);
#endif

    va_end(ArgList);
}

int main2 ()
{
    SOCKET sock, SockServ[FD_SETSIZE];
    int nFamily = DEFAULT_FAMILY;
    int nSockType = DEFAULT_SOCKTYPE;
    char *szPort = DEFAULT_PORT;
    SOCKADDR_STORAGE ssRemoteAddr;
    int i, nNumSocks, cbRemoteAddrSize, cbXfer, cbTotalRecvd;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    ADDRINFO Hints, *AddrInfo = NULL, *AI;
    fd_set fdSockSet;
    char pBuf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char szRemoteAddrString[128];

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData))
    {
        // WSAStartup failed
        return 1;
    }

    sock = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for(i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        SockServ[i] = INVALID_SOCKET;

    //
    // Get a list of available addresses to serve on
    //

    memset(&Hints, 0, sizeof(Hints));
    Hints.ai_family = nFamily;
    Hints.ai_socktype = nSockType;
    Hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST | AI_PASSIVE;

    if(getaddrinfo(NULL, szPort, &Hints, &AddrInfo))
    {
        Print(TEXT("ERROR: getaddrinfo failed with error %d\r\n"), WSAGetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //
    // Create a list of serving sockets, one for each address
    //

    i = 0;
    for(AI = AddrInfo; AI != NULL; AI = AI->ai_next) 
    {
        if (i == FD_SETSIZE) 
        {
            // getaddrinfo returned more addresses than we could use
            break;
        }

        if((AI->ai_family == PF_INET) || (AI->ai_family == PF_INET6)) // only want PF_INET or PF_INET6
        {
            SockServ[i] = socket(AI->ai_family, AI->ai_socktype, AI->ai_protocol);
            if (SockServ[i] != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                if (bind(SockServ[i], AI->ai_addr, AI->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    closesocket(SockServ[i]);
                else 
                {
                    if(nSockType == SOCK_STREAM)
                    {
                        if (listen(SockServ[i], 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                        {
                            closesocket(SockServ[i]);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    Print( 
                        TEXT("Socket 0x%08x ready for connection with %hs family, %hs type, on port %hs\r\n"), 
                        SockServ[i], 
                        (AI->ai_family == AF_INET) ? "AF_INET" : ((AI->ai_family == AF_INET6) ? "AF_INET6" : "UNKNOWN"),
                        (AI->ai_socktype == SOCK_STREAM) ? "TCP" : ((AI->ai_socktype == SOCK_DGRAM) ? "UDP" : "UNKNOWN"),
                        szPort);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(AddrInfo);

    if (i == 0) 
    {
        Print(TEXT("ERROR: Unable to serve on any address. Error = %d\r\n"), WSAGetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //
    // Wait for incomming data/connections
    //

    nNumSocks = i;

    FD_ZERO(&fdSockSet);

    for (i = 0; i < nNumSocks; i++)    // want to check all available sockets
        FD_SET(SockServ[i], &fdSockSet);

    if (select(nNumSocks, &fdSockSet, 0, 0, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        Print(TEXT("ERROR: select() failed with error = %d\r\n"), WSAGetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nNumSocks; i++)    // check which socket is ready to process
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(SockServ[i], &fdSockSet))    // proceed for connected socket
        {
            FD_CLR(SockServ[i], &fdSockSet);
            if(nSockType == SOCK_STREAM)
            {
                cbRemoteAddrSize = sizeof(ssRemoteAddr);
                sock = accept(SockServ[i], (SOCKADDR*)&ssRemoteAddr, &cbRemoteAddrSize);
                if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET) 
                {
                    Print(TEXT("ERROR: accept() failed with error = %d\r\n"), WSAGetLastError());
                    goto Cleanup;
                }

                Print(TEXT("Accepted TCP connection from socket 0x%08x\r\n"), sock);
            }
            else
            {
                sock = SockServ[i];
                Print(TEXT("UDP data available on socket 0x%08x\r\n"), sock);
            }
            break;        // Only need one socket
        }
    }

    //
    // Receive data from a client
    //

    cbTotalRecvd = 0;
    do
    {
        cbRemoteAddrSize = sizeof(ssRemoteAddr);
        cbXfer = recvfrom(sock, pBuf + cbTotalRecvd, sizeof(pBuf) - cbTotalRecvd, 0,
            (SOCKADDR *)&ssRemoteAddr, &cbRemoteAddrSize);
        cbTotalRecvd += cbXfer;
    } while(cbXfer > 0 && cbTotalRecvd < sizeof(pBuf));

    if(cbXfer == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        Print(TEXT("ERROR: Couldn't receive the data! Error = %d\r\n"), WSAGetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }
    else if(cbXfer == 0)
    {
        Print(TEXT("ERROR: Didn't get all the expected data from the client!\r\n"));
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    if(nSockType == SOCK_STREAM)
    {
        cbRemoteAddrSize = sizeof(ssRemoteAddr);
        getpeername(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&ssRemoteAddr, &cbRemoteAddrSize);
    }

    if (getnameinfo((SOCKADDR *)&ssRemoteAddr, cbRemoteAddrSize,
        szRemoteAddrString, sizeof(szRemoteAddrString), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST) != 0)
        strcpy(szRemoteAddrString, "");

    Print(TEXT("SUCCESS - Received %d bytes from client %hs\r\n"), cbTotalRecvd, szRemoteAddrString);

    //
    // Echo the data back to the client
    //

    cbXfer = 0;
    cbXfer = sendto(sock, pBuf, cbTotalRecvd, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&ssRemoteAddr, cbRemoteAddrSize);

    if(cbXfer != cbTotalRecvd)
        Print(TEXT("ERROR: Couldn't send the data! error = %d\r\n"), WSAGetLastError());
    else
        Print(TEXT("SUCCESS - Echo'd %d bytes back to the client\r\n"), cbXfer);

Cleanup:

    for(i = 0; i < nNumSocks && SockServ[i] != INVALID_SOCKET; i++)
        closesocket(SockServ[i]);

    if(sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(sock);
    }

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile bool terminate_app=false;
void terminate (int param)
{
    printf("Terminating program...\n");
    terminate_app=true;
}

void important_code(bool v)
{
    printf("Important code here %d\n", v);
}

int main ()
{
    try{
        void (*prev_fn)(int);

        prev_fn = signal (SIGINT,terminate);

        main2();
        //while(terminate_app==false)
        {
        }
    }
    catch(...){
        important_code(1);
    }
    important_code(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should cut down your example -- it is far too long. Give only the smallest (but complete!) piece of code that demonstrates the problem that you are interested in an answer to.

Comment: @Perry: I believe my question is clear. The code is for people to test with, it isn't meant to be read through as i explicitly said the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the `timeout` argument? You could use it to periodically check the termination condition (and restart the `select` if it is not true yet).

Comment: @acidzombie24: No one is going to "test with" your code, they're going to try reading it to answer your question. It is too long to read easily, so you've gotten few answers after most of an hour.

Comment: @EmilioSilva I suspect there is a way to make select return with an error. I just don't know how. If there no way to do that than select (without timeout) would be useless (or unsafe) as you cannot unwind the stack

Answer (score 2):

On POSIX `select()` will return on timeout, or when one of the descriptors is ready, or possibly it with return with `errno` set to EINTR if it's interrupted by a signal.

So, you could use the `EINTR` behavior. Just install a signal handler with the `sigaction()` function without the `SA_RESTART` (restart system calls interrupted by signals) flag. (The behavior of `signal()` differs between systems, and on some systems it can be changed via `#defines`).

Or, you could use the self-pipe trick: write to a pipe to signal that you want to exit. If your `select()` selects the read descriptor for that pipe, it will return.

Comment: The "self-pipe trick" is what you should use.  Signals are far too unsafe.

Comment: hmm, sigaction looks like its posix. I cant do it on windows. I guess i could do the self-pipe trick but that adds complexity (i need to keep track of the socket data like port # or path) +1

Answer (score 1):

Why make things so complicated with pipes? Surely the exit does not matter if it takes a few seconds. Just put a time out of (say) 3 seconds and check if an exit is required after doing the `select`.

Will it matter if it takes a few seconds to start the exit process?

Comment: Well the problem isn't so much if i use a timeout. Its more like is it possible to exit this if i don't have a timeout?

Comment: What (I guess) he's saying is: Instead of one select with no timeout, why not use an infinite loop that calls select with a, say, 1 second timeout. After every select, check if some external flag is set, and if yes, abort. This can be nicely wrapped into a function select_abortable that encapsulates the logic of checking the abort flag.

Comment: @pezcode - Exactly. A simple solution that does not require pipes. Just a simple signal handler to set a boolean to true. After select just test that boolean. Shutdown is clean as well. If it is mission critical you could also get it to give a heart beat.

Comment: @EdHeal: that wakeups the CPU unnecessarily, wasting energy.

Comment: @ninjalj The code will spend a millisecond tops between calls to `select`. If you're worried about a 0.1% increase in energy consumption (assuming for a moment energy grows linearly with time), you should probably look into asynchronous sockets to begin with. Programming is about tradeoffs, there is no perfect solution if your base assumptions are wrong in the first place.

Comment: @ninjalj - The CPU uses the same amount of energy regardless of what it is doing which your computer is switched on. It will use very little processor effort every second for a quick check.